# OpenOffice doesn't copy charts properly

Tags: openoffice, copy-paste, openoffice-calc

I'm using OpenOffice 4.0.0 and I have charts in them. Whenever I try to copy and paste them into another program it just copies and pastes a white rectangle (of the same size as the chart). I've tried selecting the chart and pressing ctrl+C. What am I doing wrong?